# How to selectively receive Azure Service Bus messages by time interval?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I've been developing an Azure Service Bus library that abstracts and simplifies a significant portion of `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` .NET API.

The following code provides an example of a subscription operation using the library:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Subscribes string types events.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventBus">The event bus.</param>
private static void SubscribeStringEvents(IEventBus eventBus)
{
    IEventBusEventHandler<string> stringEventHandler = new StringEventHandler();

    eventBus.Subscribe("topicId", stringEventHandler);
}
```

Currently, when a client subscribes to the `string` type on a specified topic, the underlying `ISubscriptionClient` will be automatically connected to the respective topic `string` subscription. As soon as the connection is established, all the messages stored in `string` subscription will be received by the registered `stringEventHandler`. Further published `string` messages will be also received by `stringEventHandler`. The only time constraint taken into consideration is that the messages should not be expired (and consequentially, moved to the dead letter queue).

However, when subscribing to the `string` type, I also want to support the possibility of only receiving messages that are published after `stringEventHandler` has been registered - past messages should remain stored in the respective `string` subscription.

What's the best approach in order to support both behaviors? Unfortunately, `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` .NET API is poorly documented.

Comment: If you set a filter with a Date type property and then subscribe to the filter event type after that date, you should be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Find a sample from Microsoft: [TopicFilters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/TopicFilters)

It uses the old `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus (4.1.3)` library. It is used a bit differently from the current version. But you may take is as a reference.

#### 1. Create a filter

```
SqlFilter sqlfilter = new SqlFilter("sys.EnqueuedTimeUtc >= @datetime");
sqlfilter.Parameters.Add("@datetime", DateTime.Parse("2019-12-04 16:56"));
Filter filter = sqlfilter.Preprocess();
```

#### 2. Get filtered Messages

```
var messages = subscriptionClient.PeekBatch(100);
Console.WriteLine("filtered messages: ");
var filteredMessages = from x in messages where filter.Match(x) select x;
var filteredMessagesList = filteredMessages.ToList();
```

> Additional tutorial:
>
> [Azure ServiceBus
> Filters](https://codehollow.com/2016/03/azure-servicebus-filters/)
>
> [Azure ServiceBus: working with datetime
> filters](https://codehollow.com/2016/09/azure-servicebus-working-datetime-filters/)

Comment: This still does not totally meet your requirement. Because all the messages will be peeked first, then the filter takes effect. Will check if the latest library can work. Anyway, it is not suggested to use Service Bus in this way. If the previous messages should not be processed, I suggest you move them to other queue.